# Creating a hotkey to enter text using python, running in background waiting for key-press

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, copy-paste

I'm trying to emulate the copy/paste functionality of my OS using a python application.

What I want to have happen is that when I press the keys, say, "Alt-X", it would paste predefined text into the currently occupied text field. Basically copy and paste but creating my own.

I've tried using pyautogui and other frameworks but I can't seem to figure out how get it to wait for key-press in the background, and then enter the text after that.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Better ask on superuser.com. Which OS ? If linux, which WM ?  I know how to do this for linux

Comment: This would hopefully be cross-platform, but Windows is what I'd like to end up running it on.

Comment: So i'm not your guy here

Comment: Well how would you do it in linux? using python? i might be able to just transfer it

Comment: With `xdotool` and the preferences of the window manager (trigger the command on a keyboard shortcut). kde, gnome and xfce4 at least can trigger this kind of events

Comment: ah, interesting. i am looking to do this in python though, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [keyboard](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard) library :

```
import keyboard

text_to_print='default_predefined_text'
shortcut = 'alt+x' #define your hot-key
print('Hotkey set as:', shortcut)

def on_triggered(): #define your function to be executed on hot-key press
    print(text_to_print)
    #write_to_textfield(text_to_print) #<-- your function
keyboard.add_hotkey(shortcut, on_triggered) #<-- attach the function to hot-key

print("Press ESC to stop.")
keyboard.wait('esc')
```

the above will print a predefined text into the terminal.

execute the script with `sudo` i.e. `sudo python program_name.py`

installation :

> sudo pip install keyboard

**Note** : According to documentation '**Works with Windows and Linux (requires sudo), with experimental OS X support**'

Comment: Thank you! i'll read up on keyboard library, however does the key definition need to match any rules? like would 'alt+x' be recognized?

Comment: @nateph, yes 'alt+x' is recognized. Try for yourself. I just went through the example provided in the GitHub library and by intuition used 'alt+x'

Comment: So this prints to the terminal, is there a way to do so that it pastes in another application while this runs in the background? also, what is the write_to_textfield function?

Comment: @nateph that is the function you are supposed to define to **paste** to your text field wherever you want(textbox, textfile etc). And you can include this program snippet in your other programs since it runs as a separate thread in the background so it won't interfere with your those programs